# How can I preview a JSON object in a Polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

In an Angular/JS app, if I have a JSON object in the scope, I can preview it on my page with something like:

```
<pre>{{myObject|json}}</pre>
```

How do I do something similar in Polymer?

When I try the same thing, I just see `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is not available in Polymer 0.8+ anymore ([was available in version 0.5](https://docs-05-dot-polymer-project.appspot.com/0.5/docs/polymer/expressions.html#filters)).

Now you can [bind to a function](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed):

```
<pre>{{_getJson(myObject)}}</pre>

<script>
   Polymer({
      properties: {
         myObject: Object
      },
      _getJson: function(myObject) {
         return JSON.stringify(myObject);
      }
   });
</script>
```

`_getJson` will be called any time `myObject` changes and the result bound to the `<pre>` element.

Comment: And you could reuse functions lik `_getJson` with shared [behaviours](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors)